# How to select child node not the entire child elements of that child elements

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

```
<categories>
<category text="Arts">
  <category>
        <category text="Design"/>
        <category text="Visual Arts"/>
   <category>
</category>
<category text="Business">
    <category>
        <category text="Business News"/>
        <category text="Careers"/>
        <category text="Investing"/>
   </category>
</category>
<category text="Comedy"/>
</categories>
```

Currently i am using

```
xDoc.Descendants("category").Where(a => a.Attribute("text").Value == "Arts").Descendants("category")
```

the above code returns me all the category element from category with attribute "Arts"
What i want  is only the node of category just below the category with attribute "Arts"
Not the category with text attribute design and visual arts. I want whole category node like under

```
 <category>
    <category text="Design"/>
    <category text="Visual Arts"/>
 <category>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, hope you still need this:

```
    string category = "Business";
    var children = xDoc.Root.Elements("category").Where(a => a.Attribute("text").Value == category).Elements();
```